# How to change the path where R.java class is generated

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I need to change the path where the `R.java` class is generated. Now it is generated in `gen/packagename/R.java`

I need to make eclipse generate it in `gen/R.java` or another path non-depending on the packagename.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to change your questions to make them more usefull to the generall public (including language points), you might be on the wrong site? This is that kind of site: all questions should be as helpfull to future people as they can be, not just a on-off fire for yourself.

Comment: i read both versions and this one is much better!

Comment: That was my mistake in my original question because of putting "<" in gen/... path that I didn't observe, so I wrongly thought that smb. modify it. I am very sorry about it.

Comment: Why do you want to move this file? This is very likely not what you want to do...

Comment: I have 2 projects that used one activity class. When I copy this activity from one project into another, I should change manually path to the R.java file in that activity. I need to do it without modify anything.

Comment: Probably you should put this activity and its belonging ressources in some library project and let both projects use that library. This should be better than copying.